# C++ global namespace access from within another namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, scope-resolution

In the C++ code below, `foobar` is defined first for a single `double` parameter, and then again for a single parameter of type `Foo`. Both are defined within the global namespace.

Within the `one` namespace, a further overload of `foobar` is defined, with a single parameter of type `Bar`. From this version of `foobar`, an unqualified call to `foobar` with a `double` argument (42.0) will fail. A similar call to `foobar`, this time qualified with the (::) scope resolution operator, also with a `double` argument, will though succeed.

On the other hand, an unqualified call to `foobar`, with an argument of type `Foo`, succeeds. A call to `foobar` with a `Foo` argument, qualified by the scope resolution operator, also succeeds.

Why do the two scenarios behave differently? I use both gcc 4.7 and clang++ 3.2.

```
struct Foo {};
struct Bar {};

double foobar(double x) { return x; }
Foo    foobar(Foo f)    { return f; }

namespace one {

  Bar foobar(Bar b) {
    //foobar(42.0); // error: can't convert to Bar
    ::foobar(42.0);

    Foo f;
      foobar(f);    // no problem
    ::foobar(f);
    return b;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Argument dependent lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211198/3-4-2-argument-dependent-name-lookup-from-n3290-draft?rq=1).

In the call `foobar(f)` functions from the namespace of `Foo` will be considered.

Doesn't work for `double` because that type is not declared in any namespace.

Comment: As an addition to the last sentence: Unqualified name lookup stops as soon as it finds a matching *name*, first considering the local scopes and only if it doesn't find any name there it will search the upper and global scopes.

Comment: @Xeo: Would that not imply that the call to `foobar(f)` would fail upon finding `foobar(Bar b)`?

Comment: @user643722: No. Since `f` is of class-type, ADL is done too, in addition to unqualified lookup.